# RequiredArgumentAttribute doesn't work correctly for InOutArguments?

Tags: xaml, workflow-foundation-4

I have implemented a WF4 activity. It has some required InArguments, one required InOutArgument and one optional OutArgument.

Since the activity was implemented in xaml (i.e. with Workflow Designer), I had to search for the info how you can mark attributes as 'required' in xaml (analogon to `[RequiredArgument]` in C#) and found following link how to do it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358733(v=vs.100).aspx

```
<x:Property Name="Operand1" Type="InArgument(x:Int32)">
  <x:Property.Attributes>
    <RequiredArgumentAttribute />
  </x:Property.Attributes>
</x:Property>
```

This works fine for all InArguments. But when implementing the tests for it, I found out that it doesn't work correctly with InOutArguments. If I run my xaml activity with `WorkflowInvoker.Invoke` in my test, without supplying any parameters, there comes an `ArgumentException` that complains about all required InArguments, but not about the required InOutArgument. If I run the activity with all required InArguments, but without the required InOutArgument, no `ArgumentException` will be thrown.

Could this be a bug in Workflow Foundation?

An interesting thing is, that if I use this activity in a workflow without supplying any parameters, I get this red  exclamation mark in Workflow Designer, that tells me which parameters need some input. And here the InOutArgument **is** mentioned, which is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Workflow engine checks the RequiredArgumentAttribute for one activity calling another. You can see this in action by creating a CodeActivity. Using breakpoints, you can watch with the debugger stop in the CacheMetadata method but an exception is thrown before the Execute method is called.

But, as you pointed out, using a WorkflowInvoker to invoke an activity with InOut/Out arguments directly does not cause an exception for InOut/Out required arguments. The RequiredArgumentAttribute requires that the argument have a binding. It does not require that the argument has a value. This can be seen by binding a reference variable with a null value. The WorkflowInvoker class automatically binds to InOut/Out arguments in order to capture the output values for its return IDictionary object.

In order to write a unit test for required InOut arguments, you have to create an activity that will bind itself to the activity you are testing. The following snippet is code I recently wrote for this exact scenario. I am using the WorkflowInvokerTest class from [CodePlex](https://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting%20Overview) to encapsulate the WorkflowInvoker.

```
public abstract class ActivityTest
{
    private class ArgumentTester : NativeActivity
    {
        public Collection<Variable> variables = new Collection<Variable>();
        public Activity Test;

        protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
        {
            base.CacheMetadata(metadata);
            metadata.AddImplementationChild(Test);
            foreach (var item in variables)
            {
                metadata.AddImplementationVariable(item);
            }
        }

        protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
        {
            context.ScheduleActivity(Test);
        }
    }

    protected WorkflowInvokerTest host;

    protected void TestForRequiredArgument(string argName)
    {
        var d = (IDictionary<string, object>)host.InArguments;
        d.Remove(argName);

        try
        {
            dynamic activityToTest = System.Activator.CreateInstance(host.Activity.GetType());

            ArgumentTester tester = new ArgumentTester
            {
                Test = activityToTest
            };

            foreach (var item in d)
            {
                Type t = typeof(Variable<>).MakeGenericType(item.Value.GetType());
                Variable v = (Variable)Activator.CreateInstance(t, item.Key + "_Var", item.Value);
                tester.variables.Add(v);
                var prop = host.Activity.GetType().GetProperty(item.Key);
                object arg = Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType, v);
                prop.SetValue(activityToTest, arg);
            }

            var h = new WorkflowInvokerTest(tester);
            h.TestActivity();

            Assert.Fail("An exception should have been thrown.");
        }
        catch (InvalidWorkflowException ex)
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(ex.Message.Contains("'" + argName + "'"));
        }
        finally
        {
            host.Tracking.Trace();
        }
    }
}
```

And then I write a test like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class WageTest : ActivityTest
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void InitializeTest()
    {
        host = new WorkflowInvokerTest(new WageActivity());
        host.InArguments.Wage = 2000;
        host.InArguments.IsFifthQuarter = false;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void WageArgumentIsRequired()
    {
        base.TestForRequiredArgument("Wage");
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void IsFifthQuarterArgumentIsRequired()
    {
        base.TestForRequiredArgument("IsFifthQuarter");
    }

    //...
}
```

It could be cleaned up a bit with generics. I'm still working on that, but you get the idea.

Comment: This looks very good.
If you have a cleaned up version with generics, I would be interested ;-)